# Custom Header and Footer using Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a requirement to add a custom header row and a custom footer row to the output of an SQL query. So the result will be like :

1st row > Header made up of a subquery or constants. It contains a few columns

n rows > columns names and corresponding data from main query . Contains large number of columns

last row > Footer row made of subquery or constants or possibly count of records from main query. It contains a few columns

Is there an easy way to do this ? or do I have to resort to writing a procedure for the required spec. I check REPHEADER and REPFOOTER keywords, but I dont see them being very helpful in this case.

Comment: I have removed the extraneous database tags (based on your title). If you are using any of those other RDBMS then please edit and re-tag your question with only the software you are using.

Comment: Do the headers/footers comply with the column datatypes?

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE] including the DDL/DML statements necessary to generate some example data and your expected output amd what **YOU** have tried to solve this and where it has not worked.

Comment: It seems these are three different queries (different projections) so it's going to be a right old hack to munge them into a single result set. The proper place for implementing this would be the front end/reporting tool.

Answer (score 0):

```
  SELECT owner, object_name
    FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER () OVER (ORDER BY owner, object_name) r, owner, object_name
            FROM dba_objects
           WHERE ROWNUM < 6
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 0, 'Owner', 'Object Name'
            FROM DUAL
          UNION ALL
          SELECT 99999999, NULL, 'Last record'
            FROM DUAL)
ORDER BY r;
```